# PyTorch - second derivative fails with multiple input values - RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Tags: vector, pytorch, derivative

This is confusing me quite a bit.  I can get second derivatives without any problem if the inputs are scalar.  But when it's a vector, PyTorch fails with: `RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn` - I already specified that I want the derivatives with respect to `a` and `requires_grad=True` which from the documentation, seems to be correct.   I made the function very simple to replicate the error.  We have a function with inputs `a` and `b` that get multiplied and summed.  Both `a` and `b` are arrays of length 3 here.  The error arises with the call to `first_derivative.backward()`  Any PyTorch veterans please respond with potential solutions, I greatly appreciate it!

```
import torch
import numpy as np

def function(a, b):
    payoff = torch.sum(torch.multiply(a, b))
    return payoff

def derivative(a, b):
    a = torch.tensor(a, requires_grad=True)
    b = torch.tensor(b, requires_grad=False)
    value = function(a, b)
    (first_derivative,) = torch.autograd.grad(value, a, create_graph=True)
    first_derivative.backward()
    second_derivative = a.grad
    return value, first_derivative, second_derivative

a = np.array([120.0,100.0,80.0])
b = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3])

value, first_derivative, second_derivative = derivative(a, b)
```

Comment: `backward()` assumes a single element tensor. You probably mean something like `first_derivative.sum().backward()` or `first_derivative.backward(torch.ones_like(first_derivative))`.

`b` also required grad I believe.

Comment: Yes that works on this small example if I add a **2 to get a 2nd derivative with first_derivative.sum().backward() I did a poor job of simplifying as my use case is slightly different.